# Getting Thread not to run until join in ruby

Tags: ruby, multithreading, join, sleep

I am getting into ruby and have been using threads for a little while now with out fully understanding them. I notice that when adding a thread to an array and if I add a sleep() command as the first command the thread does not run until I do a join which is mostly what I want. So I have 2 questions.

1.Is that suppose to happen?

2.Is there a better way to do that other then the way I'm doing it. Here is a sample code that I have to show what I'm talking about.

```
job = Array.new
10.times do |n|
    job << Thread.new do
        sleep 0.001
        puts "done #{n}"
    end 
end
#job.each do |t|
    #t.join
#end

puts "End of script"
```

Output is

```
End of script
```

If I remove the comments output is

```
done 1  
done 0  
done 7  
done 6  
done 5  
done 4  
done 3  
done 2  
done 9  
done 8  
End of script
```

So I use this now but I don't understand why it does that. Sometimes I notice even doing something like `echo hi` instead of sleep does the trick.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Timing of threads isn't a defined behavior.  Once you put them to sleep, they will be put in a queue to be run later.  You can't ever expect it to run one way or another.

Your main program doesn't take very long to run, so it is likely to happen to finish before your other threads get picked back up to run again.  Really, when you think about it, 0.001 seconds is quite a long time to computer, so spinning off 10 threads in that time is likely to happen -- but even if it takes longer, there is no guarantee the thread will resume immediately after .001 seconds.  Often there's really no guarantee it won't start before .001 seconds, either, but sleep calls usually don't end early.

When you add the join calls, you are introducing additional time into your main thread which allows the other threads time to run, so this behavior is expected.

Comment: So not sure if i understand your responds. But here is another test I did. I added sleep 0.001 and then made it do `touch file.#{n}` and when I don't have the join it does nothing when i add the join all 10 files are touched at the same time. even if I change the sleep to 5 or 20 unless I add the join nothing gets done. But I am thinking that this is not the right way to put the thread to sleep?

Comment: I thinkI have my answer now. Thanks guys.

Comment: @user1833099 unless you specifically add mechanisms to force your main thread to wait for the other threads, never expect any behavior relating performance of the different threads.  It doesn't matter what you add in terms of sleep or text output, never expect it to have a specific behavior -- unless you are adding thread specific control functions (like join)